# How to build dockerfile created by visual studio 2019 from command line?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have dockerfile created by visual studio 2019.
How can i run it manually?
bellow is the dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1-nanoserver-1903 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1-nanoserver-1903 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Client/Client.csproj", "Client/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Client/Client.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Client"
RUN dotnet build "Client.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Client.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Client.dll"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal in the folder where dockerfile is located and execute:

```sh
docker build -t image_name .
```

On successful build, execute:

```sh
docker run -d image_name
```

I advise you to read the official documentation for [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) and [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) commands. You can find additional flags which may be useful for your case.

Comment: i am getting error on the build command
Step 6/16 : COPY ["Client/Client.csproj", "Client/"]
COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder171099883\Client\Client.csproj: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: thanks for the answers i had to move the dockerfile one folder up.
after i run the second command i got some GUID, but nothing happen

Comment: can you help me to figure how to run the site.?
while running in VS the docker open me the home page

Comment: Check my answer, execute `docker run -d image_name`.

Comment: docker run -d image_name
a819dd87988c867fab9e49eaa8909054f1cb86c8b21047197f1615f217c65030

Comment: I am not aware of windows containers. What king of application are you running? A web server? If yes, which port does the application expose?

Comment: it is api on windows.
the port 63182

Comment: Ok then, try with this command `docker run -d  -p 63182:63182 image_name `. Afterwards, your api should be available at http://localhost:63182.

Comment: Problem is, the file is generated inside the project that you created the dockerfile, move the file one folder back, should work for you

Answer (score 4):

Navigate exactly to the project folder (not solution) where the dockerfile is located.
Run the command below in terminal:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile ..
```

[docker-build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?WT.mc_id=visualstudio_containers_aka_containerfastmode&view=vs-2022#docker-build)